# An error occurred: AxiosError {message: 'Network Error', name: 'AxiosError' POST http://localhost:5000/api/createUser net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongoose, fetch-api

I'm new to MERN stack and im facing a problem while posting data to the database with a form on the front-end.

`An error occurred: AxiosError {message: 'Network Error', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_NETWORK', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}`

`POST http://localhost:5000/api/createUser net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED`
`"GETTING THESE ERRORS" ,` 
`"USED THE FETCH API BEFORE AXIOS AND IT WAS GIVING 'FAILED TO FETCH ERROR"`

Signup.js(front-end)

```
const handleSubmit = async e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    try {
      **const response = await axios.post(
        'http://localhost:5000/api/createUser',
        {
          name: formData.name,
          email: formData.email,
          password: formData.password,
          address: formData.address
        },**
        {
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          }
        }
      )

      console.log(response.data)

      if (response.status === 200) {
        const data = response.data

        if (data.success) {
          console.log('success', data.success)
          alert('Registration successful. Please log in.')
        } else {
          console.log('Check your data and try again.', !data.success)
        }
      } else {
        console.log('Registration failed. Please try again later.')
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('An error occurred:', error)
    }
  }

  const handleChange = e => {
    const { name, value } = e.target
    setFormData({ ...formData, [name]: value })
  }
```

createUser.js(backend)

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const User = require('../models/User')
const {body , validationResult} = require('express-validator')

router.post('/createUser', 
  body('email', 'Enter a valid Email').isEmail(),
  body('password' , 'Password is incorrect').isLength({min: 6}),
  body('name','Enter Your Correct Name').isLength({min: 3}),
  body('location').notEmpty().withMessage('Location is required'),
  async (req, res) => {
  const errors = validationResult(req);
  if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    return res.status(400).json({errors: errors.array()})
  }
  try {
    await User.create({
        name: req.body.name,
        email: req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password,
        location: req.body.location,
        created_at: req.body.date
    })
    res.json({success: true})
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
    res.status(500).json({ success: false, error: 'Internal server error' });
  }
})

module.exports = router;
```

I have tried the fetch too!!

```
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    await fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/createUser')
    .then(res => {
      if (res.ok) {
        console.log('Success')
      } else {
        console.log('Failed')
      }
    })
    .then(data => console.log(data))
    .catch(error => console.log("error")
  }
```

but the error is still there, and i don't know why its giving me the network issue,
Also, the server is working properly on thunderclient and postman but when i put it in the browser it shows cannot GET /api/users